# jQuery .change() function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, expressionengine, volusion

I am using the .change() function on my site click here which enables users to select the quantity of their product. The problem i'm having is my chart is only linking my me to the 12 pack and not the six. I've checked in firebug and i've noticed the JS has created two buttons i believe the button that links to 6 pack is begin overlapped by the button for 12pack.

Ultimately i want the button links to change relative to the price. Does anyone know what i need to add the my code below to achieve this ?

**I only have one link button, I'm using expression engine, so the second is automatically being created**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var message = new Array();
message[1] = "$15.00";
message[2] = "$25.00";
$(document).ready(function(){            
$("#item_select").change(function()
 {
  var message_index
  message_index = $("#item_select").val();
   $(".price-item h3").empty();
    if (message_index > 0)
    $(".price-item h3").append(message[message_index]);
  });
 });
 </script>


{p_cartlink}
 <a href="http:// class="button_atc atc_{url_title}"></a>
 {/p_cartlink}
```

The issue is as this code is for a template i don't want you the product name `SLEEP-12 and SLEEP-6` I need to use the product ID. is the way can create a need ID for each button in JS then enable and disable the button. for example when you select 6-pack the 6-pack button appears and the 12-pack is disabled?

Comment: You can hide one button and show the other.. or why not just have one button and change the href depending on which item is selected?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item_select").change(function() {
        var message_index
        message_index = $("#item_select").val();
        // get the correct button
        var $button = $('.price-item right .button_atc').eq(message_index-1);
        // hide button - not the correct one
        $('.price-item right .button_atc').not($button).hide();
        // show correct button
        $button.show();
        $(".price-item h3").empty();
        if (message_index > 0) $(".price-item h3").append(message[message_index]);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two link buttons in your page, I would have only one. Then, when the index changes I would update the href property of that link button.

Comment: I only have one link button, I'm using expression engine, so the second is automatically being created

Answer (score 0):

This became a very ugly hack and the code is untested, but I thiiink it should work.

Please give it a try and let me know if you have any problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var message = ["$15.00","$25.00"];
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Init to make sure we display the correct button @ load
    $("#item_select").trigger('change');

    // The change-function
    $("#item_select").on('change'.function() {
        var message_index = $("#item_select").val();
        var message_indexn = message_index.split(' ');
        var message_id = 0;
        for ($i = 0; i < message_indexn.length; i++) {
            if (/^[\d]+$/.test(message_indexn[i])) {
                message_id = message_indexn[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        $(".price-item h3").empty();
        if (message_index > 0)
            $(".price-item h3").append(message[message_index-1]);

        $('.price-item .button_atc').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == 'http://store.bodyworksforme.com/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=SLEEP-'+message_id) {
                if ($(this).is(':hidden'))
                    $(this).show();
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).is(':visible'))
                    $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: im using a CMS so this code has to follow through on every product so the http://store.bodyworksforme.com/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=SLEEP isn't suitable

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
<select id="item_select">
    <option value="6">6 pack</option>
    <option value="12">12 pack</option>
</select>

$('.button_atc').bind('click',function(){
var val = $('#item_select').val();
window.location = "store.bodyworksforme.com/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=SLEEP"+val;
});
```

You can set id for the buttons as well and make them specific to the products, if you want.

Comment: Cheers mate, that doesn't work either, i think it's something expression engine is doing rather than JS